# Por que o padrão PSR2 exige que usemos 4 (quatro) espaços ao invés de tab?

Tags: php, psr

De acordo com um dos itens especificados pelo  padrão [PSR2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/pt-br/) (ao qual a maioria das bibliotecas PHP), temos:

- Códigos DEVEM utilizar 4 espaços para indentação, não tabs.

Sei que  o padrão existe isso, mas gostaria de saber se existe algum motivo especial.

Qual é o problema de se utilizar tabs num código PHP?

No geral (mesmo não se tratando de PHP), usar tabs ao invés de espaços pode ser um problema?

Comment: A pergunta pode ser melhorada, downvoter?

Comment: Já [pesquisa do SO do ano](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-tabsspaces) passado ficou bem claro qual é preferência do pessoal :D `\t` tabs tabs tabs

Comment: É pela preferência, existe uma página com os votos do pessoal responsável pela especificação. Alguns votaram "tab" e a maioria "espaços". Pelo que sei, a "tab" representa o espaço ocupado por uma coluna. Em alguns IDE's você pode configurar a largura da coluna, logo o espaço ocupado pela tab também será alterado. Com espaços isso não ocorre, ou seja, o espaço é o mesmo de um carácter.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes eu não sei se é só preferência. Eu já vi o git dando conflitos inexplicáveis por conta de tab.

Comment: Veja aqui o resultado da votação, na seção "A.3. Survey Results" ou "A.1. Survey Data": https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: Vamos usar `\x09` :D

Comment: Aos que não compreenderam a referencia : http://187.7.106.14/marcelo/org_comp/tabelaASCII.pdf, Hexadecimal `\x09` = Horizontal Tab HT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teve uma votação e decidiram que seriam espaços. Quotando a especificação:

> Using only spaces, and not mixing spaces with tabs, helps to avoid problems with diffs, patches, history, and annotations. The use of spaces also makes it easy to insert fine-grained sub-indentation for inter-line alignment.`

Tradução/resumo: o padrão é espaços e seguir o padrão torna a vida mais fácil, o uso de espaços também permite um controle levemente maior sobre níveis de sub-identação.

Mais que isso é só flame war.

Comment: O que é flame war (já ouvi o termo, mas esqueci)?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters algo com intuito de provocar e instigar uma discussão entre defensores de idéias opostas.(Ex.: java x c# qual é melhor)

Comment: Pessoas postando argumentos subjetivos em uma discussão infinita, não produtiva e que nunca chega a lugar nenhum porque a questão inicial não tem uma resposta objetiva.

Comment: Veja aqui o resultado da votação, na seção "A.3. Survey Results" ou "A.1. Survey Data": https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: Então, para piorar, só falta fazer flame war entre tabs e espaços, e ainda falar que um gasta "menas" memória que o outro.